# XRPL4J - Getting Started using Java tutorial does not match the versiomn 3.2 code - help needed

Tags: java, xrp

I have just started investigating XRPL.
I am following the *Get Started Using Java* tutorial at https://xrpl.org/get-started-using-java.html

The code provided is broken at the reference to creating a Wallet. The JavaDoc for Wallet says to use classes from *org.xrpl.xrpl4j.core.wallet*. But the 'core' part of the package doesn't exist.

So, I cloned the *xrpl4j* v3.2 (no .1) repo from Github into Eclipse. My plan was to search the code for clues as to how to get round this.
However,the *org.xrpl.xrpl4j.model.transactions.Address* class is missing from the *xrpl4j-core* source code. Same goes for the *Marker* class and possibly others.

I have two questions

1. is there an earlier version of the code that doesn't have this problem - or matches the Getting Started? (I just want to explore, right now)
2. Preferably, I would be grateful for a clue as to how I get round the lack of the Wallet class uxsing the v3.2 code

NB. There is tutorial code using FaucetClient which needs a 'classicAddress' value, but I don't know how to get this without using the Wallet class.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to code that works for Getting Started for xrpl4j v3.2.

It's in the xrp dev portal at:
https://github.com/XRPLF/xrpl-dev-portal/tree/master/content/_code-samples/get-started
Click the 'Java' icon and you can see the solution.
Now I have to find a way to tell the XRPL crowd.